# Powershell WPF passwordbox get value

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, passwordbox

I've just a little problem I guess.
I created a GUI with WPF for Powershell, and in this GUI is a passwordbox, now I would like to get the clear value from this passwordbox into a variable in PS.

```
<PasswordBox Name="PWBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137" FontFamily="Century Gothic"/>
```

I tested e.g.:

```
$password = $PWBox.Password
```

But I get no Value in the $password

What is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Comment: What does `$PWBox | GM` display?

Comment: Hi Paxz, quiet a lot of this things:

`TypeName   : System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox

Name       : SecurePassword

MemberType : Property

Definition : securestring SecurePassword {get;}`